# Escape Character in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, string

Please forgive me as I am a bit of an sql noob. I am trying to do an insert using the following but am having a problem with the apostrophes. I have a lots of records to insert but many have the same problem.
Is there a way of escaping them?

```
INSERT INTO  [dbo].[tb_Chefs] ([ChefHotelID], [HotelID], [ChefID],   
     [Position],  [GroupID])  
VALUES(N'b809a86e-f7f2-45b2-a240-0049f51509d7' ,N'14481', N'624', 
     N'Chef d'atelier', N'331')
GO
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`'Chef d'atelier'` becomes `'Chef d''atelier'`

[Just double them up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx)

> If a character string enclosed in
>   single quotation marks contains an
>   embedded quotation mark, represent the
>   embedded single quotation mark with
>   two single quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also you the ESCAPE clause. This allows you to define your own escape character.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this instead

`INSERT INTO  [dbo].[tb_Chefs] ([ChefHotelID], [HotelID], [ChefID], [Position],  [GroupID])

VALUES("N'b809a86e-f7f2-45b2-a240-0049f51509d7'" ,"N'14481'", "N'624'", "N'Chef d'atelier', N'331'")`

OR you could store the values you want to insert in a variable first and then use the variable in the SQL statement instead of the raw value.

Comment: This depends on SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF, which is not the default and can cause other problems if set (indexed views, computed columns etc) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx