# How to pass a network path to a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, networking, stored-procedures, path

I have a stored procedure ([previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10427451/637425)) but now I want to make the backup on a network location instead of a location on the server.

if I use the command as follow:

```
sp_doStuff '\\172.16.97.15\DbBCK\', 'MyDatabase', 'F'
```

Then I get the following error:

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot open backup device '\172.16.97.15\DbBCK\MyDatabase_Full_20120503113029.BAK'. Operating
>   system error 5(Access is denied.).
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I also tried to make a network drive of the location ('Z:') and then run the commando as follows:

```
sp_doStuff 'Z:\', 'MyDatabase', 'F'
```

Then I get this error:

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot open backup device 'Z:\MyDatabase_Full_20120503113340.BAK'. Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

But I can go to the path, the path does exist. Does anyone have a clue if this is even possible?

Comment: The first error message seems the most likely explanation - Operating system error 5(Access is denied.). The user the stored proc is running as does not have permission to access that network path.

Comment: ... and the second message indicates that drive `Z:` is not mapped for the user running the sproc.

Comment: @Filburt is right, you need to restart SQL Server to see the new backup device .

Comment: @dash I run the command with the Admin account, that account has access to the path.

Comment: @Filburt I restarted SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS), SQL Server Browser (SQLEXPRESS) and SQL Server Reporting Services (SQLEXPRESS) and still running as Admin account (I mapped it with the admin account). After the restart of services I still get the same error. Anymore suggestions?

Comment: UNC has to be accessible by the user account MSSQL services is using for security credentials. `LocalSystem` does not have any network rights (default user used by the service), try setting `NetworkService` or workgroup/domain user in `services.msc`.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **PLEASE** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using information provided by @[wqw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40691) and @[Filburt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205233/) I set my SQL EXPRESS service to use my Administrator account and then it was able to execute the command to `'\\172.16.97.15\DbBCK\'`. So many kudos to them!